# How can I parse the below array of values to XML using javascript which can also be validated with the below XSD?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse the below array of values into a XML file which can be validated using the below XSD file. I want this to be done with Javascript.

```
var myArray = [ '"elem11","elem12","elem13","elem14","elem15"',
  '"elem21","elem22","elem23","elem24","elem25"',
  '"elem31","elem32","elem33","elem34","elem35"' ]
```

XSD:

```
  <xsd:element name="myArray">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="myArray" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="elemX1" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="elemX2" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="elemX3" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="elemX4" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xsd:element name="elemX5" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: What is your runtime environment (webbrowser, node.js)?

Comment: my runtime environment is node.js

Comment: You should also give an example of the resulting xml would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your XSD the resulting XML would be structured like the following:

```
<myArray>
  <myArray>
    <elemX1></elemX1>
    <elemX2></elemX2>
    <elemX3></elemX3>
    <elemX4></elemX4>
    <elemX5></elemX5>
  </myArray>
</myArray>
```

There are several ways this can be done. Below is an example using [libxmljs](https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs).

```
var libxml = require("libxmljs");

    var myArray = [ '"elem11","elem12","elem13","elem14","elem15"',
  '"elem21","elem22","elem23","elem24","elem25"',
  '"elem31","elem32","elem33","elem34","elem35"' ]

  var doc = new libxml.Document();

  if (doc) {
    var root = doc.node('myArray');

    myArray.forEach(function(entry) {
      var entries = entry.split(",");

      var child = root.node("myArray")
      child.node("elemX1", entries[0].replace(/"/g, ''));
      child.node("elemX2", entries[1].replace(/"/g, ""));
      child.node("elemX3", entries[2].replace(/"/g, ""));
      child.node("elemX4", entries[3]);
      child.node("elemX5", entries[4]);
    });

    console.log(doc.toString());
  }
```

This produces the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myArray>
  <myArray>
    <elemX1>elem11</elemX1>
    <elemX2>elem12</elemX2>
    <elemX3>elem13</elemX3>
    <elemX4>elem14</elemX4>
    <elemX5>elem15</elemX5>
  </myArray>
  <myArray>
    <elemX1>elem21</elemX1>
    <elemX2>elem22</elemX2>
    <elemX3>elem23</elemX3>
    <elemX4>elem24</elemX4>
    <elemX5>elem25</elemX5>
  </myArray>
  <myArray>
    <elemX1>elem31</elemX1>
    <elemX2>elem32</elemX2>
    <elemX3>elem33</elemX3>
    <elemX4>elem34</elemX4>
    <elemX5>elem35</elemX5>
  </myArray>
</myArray>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I was using a different library called [xmlbuilder](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki/Examples)

I was able to get the same output with that library.